# Using Windows 10 PowerShell to bulk resize all images in a directory

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to bulk resize all images in a folder using a Windows 10 PowerShell command?

```
$path = "D:/imgs/Nature" #target directory

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
Get-ChildItem -Recurse ($path) -Include @("*.png", "*.jpg") | ForEach-Object {
    $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_)
}
```

Comment: Why not use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) instead?

Comment: There are several scripts on the script gallery that do this. Try to do it, then post what doesn't work.

Comment: wow! it was very helpful!

Comment: In case someone searches for a PS only solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454325/3772108